# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer not working on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I've got a problem with my application. I want to implement some edge screen gesture using `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` . It works very well on device with iOS 9, but on iOS 8 it doesn't. The recognizer has been added to a view of a root view controller of my app.

I've implemented `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol but the method

`(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer` is

not even called.

I thought it may be connected with another gesture recognizer, so I've implemented method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return NO;
}
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: Can we have some more code please ? How do you instantiate your UIGetureRecognizer, something like this..

Comment: I've added it in storyboard to the view of root view controller. View has userInteractionEnabled set to YES. Gesture recognizer is connected to the view and also it's delegate is connected to the view controller.

Comment: try to set `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` result to `YES`. Default value is already `NO`

Comment: Tried, and no changes.

Comment: I've posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Creating gesture recognizer in code instead of storyboard works... It's very strange that recognizer added in storyboard was working on iOS 9 but not on iOS8. I think it's a bug of Xcode 7.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Select Attributes inspector of Screen edge pan gesture and select any edge (top, left, bottom, right). It will work from storyboard.